# XAML Designer is not loading

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, win-universal-app

I am trying to develop a Universal application for Windows 10 but the XAML designer fails to load. I have tried reinstalling Visual Studio but nothing has seemed to work.

**Error**:

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

The app didn't start. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8027025B)

**Stacktrace**:

```
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.HostUtility.AppPackage.AppPackageNativeMethods.IApplicationActivationManager.ActivateApplication(String appUserModelId, String activationContext, ActivateOptions options, Int32& processId)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.HostUtility.AppPackage.DesignerWrtUtility.ActivateApplication(String appUserModelId, String activationContext, Object site, Boolean isRunningElevated)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.ActivateApplicationInternal(String appUserModelId, String activationContext, Object site)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.CreateDesignerProcess(String applicationPath, String clientPort, Uri hostUri, IDictionary environmentVariables, Int32& processId, Object& processData)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.ProcessIsolationDomain..ctor(ProcessDomainFactory factory, IIsolationBoundary boundary, AppDomainSetup appDomainInfo, IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, String baseDirectory)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary boundary)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary boundary)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.Initialize()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.CreateInstance[T](Type type)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedObjectFactory.Initialize()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerHost.Services.VSIsolationService.CreateObjectFactory(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, IObjectCatalog catalog)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolationService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, CancellationToken cancelToken, DesignerServiceEntry& entry, IServiceProvider serviceOverrides)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.IsolatedDesignerView.CreateDesignerViewInfo(CancellationToken cancelToken)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.InvokeWithCulture[T](CultureInfo culture, Func`2 func, CancellationToken cancelToken)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.c__DisplayClass10_0`1.b__0()
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

Comment: Have you try to read this subject ? [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7e9d7806-aa43-48bc-8662-575384645d12/windows-store-apps-error-0x8027025b?forum=winappswithcsharp)

Comment: I tried that but it didn't help

Comment: I have just encountered this problem as well. The VS15 designer worked a month ago, but now something's gone wrong somewhere. I have tried to repeair my VS installation, but it didn't help. I can still write xaml and run my app. It's simply the designer that's dead... I'm on the enterprise version if this helps anyone identify the problem.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: Did you Find any Solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem. Using VS 2015 Enterprise and Win8.1 x64. Have solved it this way:

1. Start the Firewall service (was switched off)
2. Changed UAC to recommended level (was switched off)
3. Logged in as Microsoft user account (as I suppose, this would be the crucial)
4. Started the Windows Store App (have read this is the origin of all problems)
5. Started VS. After this designer began to work
6. Reboot the system, restore all settings, incl. Firewall & UAC
   At the end of all, designer is working properly under any user, even if MS user account is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I started noticing this problem some three weeks ago and I visited the Visual Studio Community 2017 forum. I encountered the problem using the more recent versions, 15.7.5, 15.7.6, 15.8.0, 15.8.1. I finally found that the problem was related to the choice of Target Version/Minimum Version you have to make while creating UWP project. I always worked with a Blank UWP project and modifying it along the way.

If you are interested in complete details I have it in my post here:
http://hodentekhelp.blogspot.com/2018/08/how-did-you-fix-unhandled-exception-app.html

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by updating (minimum version).
I suggest that you check whether the selected (minimum version) (sdk) is installed or not

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34985884)

Answer (score 0):

**Short word**: Just fixed it by updating the "Minimum Version" greater than build 16299.

**Suggestion**: Make sure to check the help link ("[Which version should I choose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/updates-and-versions/choose-a-uwp-version)") when creating new solution if you're confused, shown as below.

[image]

In the page "Choose a UWP Version", it tells that "**Projects using .NET Standard 2.0 must have a Minimum Version of Build 16299 or later**".

Btw, the "Target version" shows the list of Windows SDK installed on your machine.

Answer (score -3):

I just fixed this problem myself. Apparently this error is connected with some windows system files which are most likely corrupted. My app store didn't work either, but after I fixed visual studio, my store worked again as well.

In some cases the error might be less severe, and stem from a wrong configuration.

I looked around the web and found a series of recommendations, going from small fixes to more serious and throughout methods. I'll list them here.

---

**1) Fix permissions in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT**

1. Open the Command Prompt with admin rights.
2. Right click on HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.
3. Click on "Permissions" and in popup click on "Add".
4. In 2nd Popup click on "Advanced".
5. In 3rd Popus click on "Find Now".
6. In "Search Results" click on "All Application Packages" and then click "Ok".
7. Now in 2nd Popup "Select Users or Groups" click again "Ok".
8. In Permissions select under Allow "Read" and Click "Ok".
9. Close the Registry Editor. No need to restart.

[As adviced on the bottom of this page.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/276f8170-21f9-4f2d-a96e-9d4e84d10511/an-unhandled-exception-has-occured-xaml-designer) This did *not* work for me.

---

**2) Run this Powershell Command in Command Prompt**

Open the Command Prompt with Admin rights.

Copy paste the line below into the prompt and run it.

```
PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command "& {$manifest = (Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.WindowsStore).InstallLocation + '\AppxManifest.xml' ; Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register $manifest}"
```

[Tip found here.](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ouc1too/2015/08/17/windows-app-store-doesnt-load-after-windows-10-upgrade/) This did *not* work for me.

---

**3) Clear the LocalCache**

Go to the following place on your pc. Remember to replace *user_name* with your own user name.

```
C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.WindowsStore_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalCache
```

Delete the folders content.

[Tip seen here.](http://C:%5CUsers%5Cuser_name%5CAppData%5CLocal%5CPackages%5CMicrosoft.WindowsStore_8wekyb3d8bbwe%5CLocalCache) This did *not* work for me.

---

**4) Try running a SFC scan**

Open the Command Prompt with admin rights. Write the command below and let it complete.

```
sfc /scannow
```

[As seen here.](http://www.howtogeek.com/222532/how-to-repair-corrupted-windows-system-files-with-the-sfc-and-dism-commands/) This did *not* work for me. It did however verify that I had some corrupted files. It wasn't able to fix/restore them though...

---

**5) Run the DISM tool, then try SFC again**

Open Command Prompt with admin rights. Run the command below.

```
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
```

If it completes successfully, run the `sfc /scannow` command again.

[As seen here.](http://www.howtogeek.com/222532/how-to-repair-corrupted-windows-system-files-with-the-sfc-and-dism-commands/) This did *not* work for me.

---

**6) Repair Windows 10**

***Warning!*** This process deletes all your programs and apps. It does however leave your files alone. E.g. my dropbox folder still had its files after running the repair.

**Please backup anything you do not want to lose to an external harddrive, the cloud or to a repository.**

1. Click the start button.
2. Click settings.
3. Click update and security.
4. Click recovery.
5. Click reset this PC and follow the instructions.

[As seen here.](http://www.howtogeek.com/222532/how-to-repair-corrupted-windows-system-files-with-the-sfc-and-dism-commands/) This finally did the trick for me. My designer now loads and my win app store also works again.

---

There is most likely more tips and tricks to fix this kind of problem, but I hope the above gives you a lead on how to fix your problem.

Good luck, and please reply if any of the above worked for you :)

Comment: Your method destroyed my Store App!

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that :( But please note none of these are "my" methods. You can find the source for each method in my answer.