# XAML designer in WIndows 10 on visual studio community 2015 does not load

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, windows-10-universal

I am stuck with this from past two days and have tried everything advised on google.
Here is what all I have already done..

1.change the target version of solution from 10586 to 10240 and vice versa.

2. Update the windows 10 with all possible updates
3. Update visual studio community 2015
4. Repair Visual Studio.
5. Checked the Enable XAML editor.
6. running the firewall

is there any other option other than these? I am facing this on a new Windows 10 device. it never had any previous versions of any other OS.I am trying to build Universal app. It still gives me System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
The app didn't start. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8027025B)

Comment: My best friend's 12 year-old son is using Visual Studio Community 2015 on Windows 10 to build a Windows Universal App together with me, and there is no visual XAML designer. We're coding the UI in the XAML text editor and then run the App to see if it looks good. So my assumption is, there is not visual XAML designer included in the Community edition. But I'm not sure. But I have to say, at work I'm using the Enterprise edition, which has a visual designer, but I'm using it only for previewing, as you don't have good control over the layout there.

Comment: I had this same issue, but all it took was updating win10 and making sure I had all the packages installed. I'm doing a win10 IoT UWP proj right now that would be darn near impossible without the designer so I know there's just NOT a visual designer, but what's missing to provide it I'm not sure in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repair Windows 10

Warning! This process deletes all your programs and apps. It does however leave your files alone.

Please backup anything you do not want to lose to an external harddrive, the cloud or to a repository.

```
Click the start button.
Click settings.
Click update and security.
Click recovery.
Click reset this PC and follow the instructions.
```

Comment: Resetting Windows 10 helped. I could do work for few days. but now again it has  run into problem. I have no idea how many times in a month I have to reset my PC! Is there any other way?

Comment: Please check with this link    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33171926/xaml-designer-is-not-loading